# Chartjs won't render chart with Requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, chart.js

I am trying to render a chart using Chartjs and Requirejs, but it fails to render or provide error messages. I know that I am probably tired and missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out.

The line in my HTML to hold the canvas for the chart is as follows:

```
 <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```

My Requirejs file is as follows. It is here that I suspect the issue:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: "jquery-2.1.1.min",
    bootstrap: "bootstrap.min",
    chartjs: "Chart.min"
},
shim: {
    bootstrap: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'Bootstrap'
    },
}
});

requirejs(['bootstrap'], function (Bootstrap) {
return {};
});


require(['chartjs'], function (Chart) {
// Use Chart.js as normal here.
var randomScalingFactor = function () { return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) };
var lineChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}

window.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
}
// Chart.noConflict restores the Chart global variable to it's previous owner
// The function returns what was previously Chart, allowing you to reassign.
var chartjs = Chart.noConflict();

});
```

Comment: If you are using Chart.js through bower, the version is outdated and *DOES NOT* support RequireJS. The latest version from GitHub does, so get that one.

Comment: I pulled the one from GitHub (which is awesome by the way! Great work on this tool). It must be how I am trying to call it/load it because it doesn't show as called. Per Louis, I will try the jquery ready or requires domready

Comment: If anyone using chart.js with angularjs using requirejs then please look over the, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288001/how-to-use-chart-js-with-angular-chart-using-requirejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is consistent with the event handler you give to `window.onload` not being fired at all.

By the time RequireJS starts executing the code in your `require(['chartjs']` call, the `load` event has most likely already happened. What you could do is use something like jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or RequireJS' [`domReady`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload).

By the way, this code is bizarre:

```
requirejs(['bootstrap'], function (Bootstrap) {
return {};
});
```

If you are just loading bootstrap, you could reduce it to `requirejs(['bootstrap'])`. But note that all loads are asynchronous so the only thing this does is tell RequireJS to load Bootstrap, which will happen at some indeterminate point in the future.

Comment: Thankd for the clarity. I will try ready or domready and post what happens.

Comment: If anyone using chart.js with angularjs using requirejs then please look over the, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288001/how-to-use-chart-js-with-angular-chart-using-requirejs