# how to use chart.js with angular-chart using requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, chart.js, angular-amd

Trying to implement lazy load using **requirejs**. *Everything is fine when I am not using charts.* But when I want to use charts(angular charts), not going to sucseed! Using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) with [angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).

**Here is main.js:**

```
 require.config({ 
baseUrl: "http://localhost/ums/angular/js",
    paths: {
        'angular': 'lib/angular.min',
        'ngRoute': 'lib/angular-route.min',
        'flash': 'lib/angular-flash',
        'angular-loading-bar': 'lib/loading-bar.min',
        'ngAnimate': 'lib/angular-animate.min',
        'ui.bootstrap': 'lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0',
        'uniqueField': 'admin/directives/angular-unique',
        'input_match': 'admin/directives/angular-input-match',
        'uniqueEdit': 'admin/directives/angular-unique-edit',
        'angularAMD': 'lib/angularAMD.min',
        'chart.js': 'lib/Chart.min', 
        'angular-chart':'lib/angular-chart.min',   
        'app': 'admin/app',
        },
        waitSeconds: 0,
         shim: { 
         'angular': { exports: 'angular'},
        'angularAMD': { deps: ['angular']},
        'angular-chart': { deps: ['angular','chart.js']},
        'ngRoute':{ deps: ['angular']},
        'angular-loading-bar':{ deps:['angular'] },
        'ngAnimate': { deps:['angular'] } ,
        'ui.bootstrap': {deps: ['angular'] },
        'uniqueField': {deps: ['angular'] },
        'input_match': {deps: ['angular'] },
        'uniqueEdit': {deps: ['angular'] },
        'flash': {deps: ['angular'] },
        },
        deps: ['app']
    });
```

**Here is app.js:**

```
var base_url="http://localhost/ums/";
define(['angularAMD', 'ngRoute','flash','angular-loading-bar','ngAnimate','uniqueField','input_match','angular-chart'], function (angularAMD) {
var app = angular.module('angularapp', ['ngRoute','flash','angular-loading-bar','ngAnimate','uniqueField','input_match','angular-chart']);  
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard', angularAMD.route({
                title : 'Dashboard',
                controller : 'dashboardCtrl',
                templateUrl : base_url+'angular/partials/admin/dashboard.php',
                controllerUrl: base_url+'angular/js/admin/controllers/dashboardCtrl.js'
            }))

//.......................all routing ............//
 .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/dashboard'
        });
}]);
app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        document.title = $route.current.title;
    });
}]);


  // Bootstrap Angular when DOM is ready
    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

});
```

**How to implement dependancy between them?**
Any suggestions? any examples?

Comment: you can try 2 things, add `chart.js`  in the define() block of app.js and remove or increase waitSecond: 0 to 60 or something

Comment: `waitSecond` timeout setting for requireJS to wait for an JS module to be loaded. And if there're any module need more than 0s to be loaded. It will considering as failed.

Comment: requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
        console.error("There is an error occurred due to network connection. \nPlease reload the page: \n\n "+err);
    } else {
        console.error("There is an error occurred due to network connection. \nPlease reload the page: \n\n "+err);
    }
};

Comment: Use the code above in your `main.js` it will help to log out requireJS error in browser's console.

Comment: @Linh Pham  - waitSecond = 0 disables the timeout.

Comment: @LinhPham: (may be)Its because of that module ID `chart.js` . So how can I tackle with this. Because browser console says `chart.js not found`, even my file name is Chart.min.js

Comment: @SujVan have you added `'chart.js'` into define() block of `app.js`?

Comment: @LinhPham: In define block of app.js there is `angular-chart` And I already mentioned in `shim` that `angular-chart` is depend on `chart.js`. So do I need to also define chart.js there too in define block of app.js. No, I think so.!

Comment: @SujVan can you tell me the exactly error that got logged by browser console? What is the url you saw there?

Comment: @SujVan and the newly updated answer seem legit, avoid to use `.js` because it may confuse requireJS in someway (I never know or heard, but better not using some sensitive character, for example: `'\'` )

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

> If a module ID has one of the following characteristics, the ID will
>   **not** be passed through the "baseUrl + paths" configuration, and just be
>   treated like a regular URL that is relative to the document:
>   • Ends in ".js".
>   • Starts with a "/".
>   • Contains an URL protocol, like "http:" or "https:".

This will kick in for your chart.js module and RequireJS will attempt to load chart.js from the directory that contains the HTML page running RequireJS

Note - you should be able to see this in your Developer Tools > Network tab. Note that the request for chart.js doesn't go to the path that you expect.

---

This seems like a bug (with angular-chart) - see a similar issue for typeahead.js - https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1211

---

There are a couple of ways to fix / workaround this

1. Modify angular-chart code to make the expected module ID as something without a dot - say `chartjs`. Then change chart.js in your above configuration to chartjs. This would be correct way.
2. Rename you chart.min.js file to chart.js and put it in the same folder as your html file running RequireJS. This would at best be a very very temporary fix.
3. Set nodeIDCompat to true - this will make module ID *something.js* equivalent to *something*. Then change the module ID in your configuration to `chart`. So something like

   ```
   require.config({
       nodeIdCompat: true,
       paths: {
           'chart': base_url + '/lib/Chart.min',
            ...
   ```

If you are using r.js to compress / consolidate, you might want to just test that too before settling on this workaround.

Comment: Cool! It should work if you put chart.js in that path, or a better idea would be to set baseUrl

Comment: Hi, now its not giving any error in console, don't know hows that error has gone.! Now the charts are not going to shown.Means `<canvas ... >` tag is not working?

Comment: If Chart.js has loaded properly, it could simply be a problem with the sizing. Make sure you have a width and height set on the canvas element (directly - width="300" height="200")

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. The error is still exists! And I have putted up the file where that error has been saying. Still the same.

Comment: Its error: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/ums/admin/chart.js"` But my file name `Chart.min.js`. And dependancy name is chart.js. You can look over the above code mentioned in post.

Comment: If you are saying that in your answer, so hows my other modules get loaded? only the problem with chart.js. As per your answer my module name should not contain .js. So angular-chart uses that chart.js module in their js.So how can I tackle with THIS?

Comment: Your other modules don't end in .js. Just a minute - updating answer. Cheers!

Comment: If I am going to remove that ending .js, what other changes do i need to do? And waiting for your updated answer!

Comment: Changing the angular chart code affecting(giving inject error). Applying 1, 2,3 gibes same error : `Failed to instantiate module angularapp due to:
[$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: NOTE: Post Updated (* baseUrl: used instead of using javascript global variable.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82967/discussion-between-potatopeelings-and-sujvan).